# Not able to search for a specific sub-string in a given string

Tags: python, string, substring

```
str_search = "DD09"

str_1 = "DD09 High speed status"
Str_2 = "Dd09 High speed status"

str.find (str_search)
print(str)
```

Output: DD09 High speed status

Why am not able to print `Str_2`? How do I overcome this issue?

Comment: What do you mean "not able to print Str_2" ?

Comment: Dd09 is present in Str_2 ..it is not doing case insensitive search. This is the reason it is not printing the second string . How to overcome this issue?

Comment: If you had asked _that_ question, that would have made sense.

Answer (score 1):

Make both strings lowercase before searching:

```
str_search = "DD09"

str_1 = "DD09 High speed status"
Str_2 = "Dd09 High speed status"

position = Str_2.lower().find(str_search.lower())
print(position)
```